# trigger.io and audio

Tags: iphone, ios, trigger.io

I'm trying to play audio files in an iOS app built with trigger.io. As there's no method to play sounds in the trigger API, I'm using the HTML Audio Element. It works fine on iOS 6 and the mp3 is played as expected, but on iOS 5 nothing happens and no error message is logged in the console.

Any idea why?

Comment: Are you testing on a device or the simulator (and if its a device, what device)? Could you give us a code snippet for what you are trying so we can have a go at reproducing the problem?